# Angular UIGrid Column Header Label, Sort Priotiy, and Menu Overlaps

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I noticed that the items in the column header begin to overlap if there isn't enough room in the header. If the column is too narrow, the label will be truncated (e.g. "Gender" becomes "Ge..."). Ideally, the sort icon should sit next to the label and the column menu should float right. Or both sort icon and column menu icon should float to the right.

Here's a preview:
http://plnkr.co/edit/29TK44Vor4F45C8hSBNI?p=preview

I tried updating the header containers so that they flow one after the other but was unsuccessful

```
.ui-grid-header-cell-label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}

.ui-grid-column-menu-button {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to make it so that the icons don't over lap? Ideally, the column width should not be less than the truncated text + the width of the sorter + the width of the column menu and each element should sit next to each other:

[Label /\   =]

I tried a number of things with the CSS but could not get it to work.

[image: Screenshot of column header for Angular ui-grid]

Thanks!